# How to select data from excel sheet categorically in Flutter

Tags: excel, flutter, dart

I am a beginner in Flutter, I have a database of product items in a General Store in Excel file. I want to select the data from the excel database using their categories(the database has a column of categories)(such as Medicine or Automobile Items). Then I want to use the data in form of cards to show customers the product image and info. Please suggest me to how to select the data from an excel file (like ordering the data as per some condition).

WorkAround - I thought of converting .xlsx to .csv then to .json file and then finally storing it in Firebase which is the database I am currently using in my project. But the problem with that would be, the download usage would increase which would lead me to cost money.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to store the data of your items. Then hard code items into a file and use that file to look up in your application.

For example;

```
// Data Structre
class Item {
  int id;
  String category;

  Item({this.id, this.category});
}

// Hard coded data storage
List<Item> items = [Item(id: 1, category: 'Medicine'), Item(id: 2, category: 'Automobile')];

// Methods to fetch data
List<Item> getItemsByCategory(String category) {
  return items.where((item) => item.category == category).toList();
}
```